# HOW do I left align my items in my navigation bar using vue material?

Tags: html, vue-material

I want to left align the following items in my navigation bar : Service, Support, and Sign in.

This is the code:

```
<md-whiteframe md-elevation = "1" class = "main-toolbar">
  <md-theme md-name = "teal" >

   <md-toolbar class = "navigation md-primary"  >


<router-link class = "nav-link " :to = " { name: 'Home' }">levi</router-link>



    <router-link class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Product' }">
        Service 
    </router-link> 

         <router-link class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Support' }">
        Support
    </router-link>

        <router-link class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Sign' }">
        Sign in
    </router-link>

</md-toolbar>
    </md-theme>

       </md-whiteframe>
```

[image: Toolbar]

The above image is how it looks now. I want to left align all except the levi item.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code before the Service router-link:

```
<v-spacer></v-spacer>
```